# Dynamic change Microsoft BOT Framework Form's Field Step: hiding and showing the confirmation

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm new to MS BOT Framework.
I changed MS github [MultiDialogsBot.sln](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/MultiDialogsBot.sln) , I added a HotelsQuery property to init Form's Field value at HotelsDialog.cs,

```
public class HotelsDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public HotelsQuery _HotelsQuery { get; set; }
    public HotelsDialog()
    {
        _HotelsQuery = new HotelsQuery{
            Destination = "Taiwan",
            CheckIn = new DateTime(2017,10,29),
            Nights = 3
        };
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Welcome to the Hotels finder!");
        var hotelsFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildHotelsForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call(hotelsFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterHotelsFormDialog);
    }

    public IForm<HotelsQuery> BuildHotelsForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<HotelsQuery> processHotelsSearch = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ok. Searching for Hotels in {state.Destination} from {state.CheckIn.ToString("MM/dd")} to {state.CheckIn.AddDays(state.Nights).ToString("MM/dd")}...");
        };
        var destField = new FieldReflector<HotelsQuery>(nameof(HotelsQuery.Destination))
            .SetActive((state) =>
            {
                //depend on _HotelsQuery's values
                bool isActive = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_HotelsQuery.Destination);
                if (!isActive) state.Destination = _HotelsQuery.Destination;
                return isActive;
            });

        var checkInField = new FieldReflector<HotelsQuery>(nameof(HotelsQuery.CheckIn))
            .SetActive((state) =>
            {
                //depend on _HotelsQuery's values
                bool isActive = _HotelsQuery.CheckIn == DateTime.MinValue;
                if (!isActive) state.CheckIn = _HotelsQuery.CheckIn;
                return isActive;
            });
        var nightsField = new FieldReflector<HotelsQuery>(nameof(HotelsQuery.Nights))
            .SetActive((state) =>
            {
                //depend on _HotelsQuery's values
                bool isActive = _HotelsQuery.Nights == 0;
                if (!isActive) state.Nights = _HotelsQuery.Nights;
                return isActive;
            });


        var form = new FormBuilder<HotelsQuery>()
            .Field(destField)
            .Message("Looking for hotels in {Destination}...")
            .Field(checkInField)
            .Message("Check in {CheckIn}...")
            .Field(nightsField)
            .Message("Nights : {Nights}...")
            .Confirm("Is this your selection?\n {*}", state =>
            {
                //clean all fields for showing fields in confirmation 
                _HotelsQuery.Destination = string.Empty;
                _HotelsQuery.CheckIn = DateTime.MinValue;
                _HotelsQuery.Nights = 0;
                return true;
            }, new List<string>())
            .Message("Thanks you ...")
            .OnCompletion(processHotelsSearch)
            .Build();
        return form;
    }


    public async Task ResumeAfterHotelsFormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<HotelsQuery> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var searchQuery = await result;

            var hotels = await this.GetHotelsAsync(searchQuery);

            await context.PostAsync($"I found in total {hotels.Count()} hotels for your dates:");

            var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
            resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

            foreach (var hotel in hotels)
            {
                HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
                {
                    Title = hotel.Name,
                    Subtitle = $"{hotel.Rating} starts. {hotel.NumberOfReviews} reviews. From ${hotel.PriceStarting} per night.",
                    Images = new List<CardImage>()
                    {
                        new CardImage() { Url = hotel.Image }
                    },
                    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                    {
                        new CardAction()
                        {
                            Title = "More details",
                            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                            Value = $"https://www.bing.com/search?q=hotels+in+" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hotel.Location)
                        }
                    }
                };

                resultMessage.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
            }

            await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
        }
        catch (FormCanceledException ex)
        {
            string reply;

            if (ex.InnerException == null)
            {
                reply = "You have canceled the operation. Quitting from the HotelsDialog";
            }
            else
            {
                reply = $"Oops! Something went wrong :( Technical Details: {ex.InnerException.Message}";
            }

            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Hotel>> GetHotelsAsync(HotelsQuery searchQuery)
    {
        var hotels = new List<Hotel>();

        // Filling the hotels results manually just for demo purposes
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var random = new Random(i);
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel()
            {
                Name = $"{searchQuery.Destination} Hotel {i}",
                Location = searchQuery.Destination,
                Rating = random.Next(1, 5),
                NumberOfReviews = random.Next(0, 5000),
                PriceStarting = random.Next(80, 450),
                Image = $"https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=35&txt=Hotel+{i}&w=500&h=260"
            };

            hotels.Add(hotel);
        }

        hotels.Sort((h1, h2) => h1.PriceStarting.CompareTo(h2.PriceStarting));

        return hotels;
    }
}
```

I have trouble after the confirmation shows. When a user answers yes, BOT will ask CheckIn's prompt.

Why does it not go to the OnCompletion event?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing out the values in the .Confirm

Try something like this:

```
var form = new FormBuilder<HotelsQuery>()
            .Field(destField)
            .Message("Looking for hotels in {Destination}...")
            .Field(checkInField)
            .Message("Check in {CheckIn}...")
            .Field(nightsField)
            .Message("Nights : {Nights}...")
            .Confirm("Is this your selection?\n {*}", state =>
            {
                if (_HotelsQuery.Destination == string.Empty ||
                    _HotelsQuery.CheckIn == DateTime.MinValue ||
                    _HotelsQuery.Nights == 0)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }, new List<string>())
            .Message("Thanks you ...")
            .OnCompletion(processHotelsSearch)
            .Build();
```

Comment: thanks Eric. i want hide fieldsteps but show fields info at confirmation. The confirmation won't show fields info  if i don't clear values let fieldsteps active  in .Confirm .